# How do I determine pages that contain layouts with content-item of certain entity object in DNN module 2sxc programmatically?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have entity `ListSettings` which is used as Content-Item type for 2 layouts. Each layout is used 3 times on different pages.
The code I'm writing is not executed on the page - it's outside of 2sxc module.
So I wan't to find out on which page each object of entity `ListSettings` is. TabId is the best. Filtering by layout could be helpful as well since I need 3 tabIds that use 1 of the 2 layouts.
How do I do that programmatically? There's a lot of data inside of each entity including some relationships, children, parents and so on. Also I'm sure that all this data could be taken from the database manually, but it seems to be a hard way for me.

Bottom line: I have 6 entities. I want to get their tabIds and layouts programmatically. Layouts are optional but would be good.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite challenging, because there are so many steps involved. But you can find something that does something similar here https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/2sa110/page

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```cs
  // CONSTANTS
  // this key is used in module settings
  const string SettingsCG = "ToSIC_SexyContent_ContentGroupGuid";

  // create array with all 2sxc modules in this portal
  List<ModuleInfo> GetAllModulesOfPortal(int portalId) {
    var mc = ModuleController.Instance;
    var dnnMod2sxcContent = mc.GetModulesByDefinition(portalId, "2Sexy Content");
    var dnnMod2sxcApp = mc.GetModulesByDefinition(portalId, "2Sexy Content App");
    var mergedMods = new ModuleInfo[dnnMod2sxcContent.Count + dnnMod2sxcApp.Count];
    dnnMod2sxcContent.CopyTo(mergedMods);
    dnnMod2sxcApp.CopyTo(mergedMods, dnnMod2sxcContent.Count);
    var allMods = mergedMods
      .Where(m => m.DefaultLanguageModule == null)
      .Where(m => !m.IsDeleted)
      .Where(m => m.ModuleSettings.ContainsKey(SettingsCG));
    return allMods.ToList();
  }
```

Comment: After I was messing with the code for a long time I've found another way to do it but thanks for the tip anyway. Probably I'll get back to it in the future if I need it.